# a lot of errors with feedwordpress

Tags: feed

I've been using feedwordpress for more than 1 year, but after some changes in my site, this plugin caused a lot of errors in my site frontend & backend. Unfortunately I don't remember all the changes I made in the database and my wordpress site, and also I deleted my error log so i can't know the exact day this started to happen.

When I tried to deactivate the plugin, the errors disappear.

When I tried to turn off the debugging mode of the plugin, the errors still persist.

When I tried to uninstall, delete, and reinstall the pluin, I got errors still.

I tried to install it on fresh wordpress install on my localhost, and there, it works fine.

```
Strict Standards: Declaration of FeedWordPress_Walker_Category_Checklist::start_el() 
should be compatible with 
Walker_Category_Checklist::start_el(&$output, $category, $depth, $args, $id = 0)
in /home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-content/plugins/
feedwordpress/feedwordpress-walker-category-checklist.class.php on line 13

Strict Standards: Redefining already defined constructor for class 
FeedWordPress_File in /home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-content/plugins/feedwordpress
/feedwordpress_file.class.php on line 11

 Strict Standards: Non-static method FeedWordPress::needs_upgrade() 
 should not be called statically in /home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-content/plugins
 /feedwordpress/feedwordpress.php on line 144

Strict Standards: Non-static method FeedWordPressCompatibility::link_category_id() 
should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in 
/home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-content/plugins/feedwordpress/feedwordpress.php 
on line 1699

Strict Standards: Non-static method FeedWordPressSettingsUI::is_admin() 
should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in 
/home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-content/plugins/fwp-sic-em/SicEm.php on line 46

Strict Standards: call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid 
callback, non-static method FeedWordPress::admin_api() should not be called
statically in /home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-includes/plugin.php on line 406

Strict Standards: Non-static method FeedWordPressSettingsUI::is_admin() 
should not be called statically, assuming $this from incompatible context in 
/home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-content/plugins/feedwordpress/feedwordpress.php on line 1246
```

This is the log_error at the beginning of this issue

```
[02-Nov-2013 14:31:20 Africa/Cairo] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/p in Unknown on line 0
[02-Nov-2013 14:31:20 Africa/Cairo] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_sqlite: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    c in Unknown on line 0
[02-Nov-2013 14:31:20 Africa/Cairo] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library '/usr/local/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20090626/s in Unknown on line 0
[02-Nov-2013 14:31:20 Africa/Cairo] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: pdo_mysql: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP    co in Unknown on line 0
[02-Nov-2013 14:31:20 Africa/Cairo] PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: SourceGuardian: Unable to initialize module
Module compiled with module API=20090626
PHP  in Unknown on line 0
[02-Nov-2013 12:31:20 UTC] PHP Strict Standards:  Declaration of FeedWordPress_Walker_Category_Checklist::start_el() should be compatible with Walker_Ca in /home/elnhrda/public_html/e/wp-content/plugins/feedwordpress/feedwordpress-walker-category-checklist.class.php on line 13
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: the person who down voted the question please tell me why you do that?

Comment: **-1** — for not taking the time to ask the question properly; lack of any helpful information; and what appears to be, you being overly dependent on the community, as in asking, I have a problem, do all your research and fix it for me. You need to spend more time thinking, then write the question with all the details you can provide, and also tell us what you've actually tried. Once you've done your part right, I'll gladly remove the downvote.

Comment: i have already searched more & more, but with no any benefits & found also a lot of sites have the same issue but after trying to test it on a fresh install with no problems so i come here to ask not to make inconvenience, i will update the question to with my attempts

Comment: The fact that the plugin works fine on a fresh wordpress install tells you that the problem could be caused by your theme or one of the other plugins in use on your site. Try deactivating all plugins, then activate one-by-one to identify the culprit. If it's not the plugin, it could be the theme itself. Switch to twenty thirteen and see if the issue still persists. If it doesn't, then you'll have to fix your theme's incompatibility.

Comment: of course i tried this before comes here i think this is from the database or because i used `'cache_results' => false` with `get posts` in some tests

Answer (score 0, accepted):

after more than 12 hours working, searching & testing the problem is

`feedwordpress` not working with `php 5.4` i upgraded my `php` in the last few days

hope this help people who have the same issue

sorry if i don't give alot of information in my question